# Wie sagt man "in the back of my mind " auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, idiom

> In the back of my mind I knew she wasn't right for me, but I loved her anyway.
>
> Im Hinterkopf wußte ich, dass sie nicht die Richtige für mich ist, jedoch habe ich sie sowieso geliebt.

Ich weiß nicht, ob *Im Hinterkopf* in diesem Zusammenhang richtig ist. Wäre *in Hintergedanken* eine Alternative?

Comment: `Hingergedanken` is a `hidden agenda`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "unterbewusst" or "im Unterbewusstsein" would be an even more appropriate translation here.

> Im Unterbewusstsein wusste ich, dass sie nicht die Richtige für mich ist, dennoch habe ich sie geliebt.

"Hintergedanken" intends you have another plan while performing the action described.

Comment: Es ist das, was in der Übersetzung am besten passt und entspricht dem, was man in der Situation m.E. nach sagen würde. Also nicht falsch.

Comment: Wenn man es wörtlich übersetzt, mag das stimmen. Nur sagt doch niemand *Im Unterbewusstsein wusste ich...*! Im Deutschen würde man von "Bauchgefühl" sprechen oder sagen "Mein Bauch sagte mir..."

Comment: welches original?

Comment: Naja, der OP sagt ja, er weiß nicht, ob seine Übersetzung korrekt ist. Fachlich ist sie das, aber idiomatisch würde man das vermutlich so nicht sagen - aber das ist meine Meinung. Wie gesagt: wortwörtlich übersetzt stimmt das (bis auf das *sowieso geliebt*, was *trotzdem geliebt* heißen müsste).

Comment: Naja, es gibt halt idiomatische Ausdrücke - "In the back of my mind" sagt der Engländer und auch wenn wir dafür erstmal keine 1:1 Übersetzung haben ist uns ja klar, was er damit sagen will. Wir haben stattdessen das mit dem "Gefühl im Bauch" und es wird umgekehrt auch so sein, dass es verstanden wird, aber nicht wörtlich übersetzt wird. Manche Sachen kann man einfach nicht 1:1 in "gutes Deutsch" übersetzen. Da gibt es noch weitere Ausdrücke, die - wenn wörtlich übernommen - im Deutschen einfach holprig klingen. Mein Lieblingsbeispiel: "Am Ende des Tages".

Comment: Das ist richtig, dennoch würde ich das, was er übersetzen will, so sagen, wie ich es vorgeschlagen habe. Bauchgefühl ist da eher noch etwas anderes. Aber letztendlich ist das wohl eine Sache des Bauchgefühls :)

Comment: ich lehne *im Unterbewusstsein* ab; es wird auch hier nicht mit erwähnt: http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/back+of+my+mind.html

Answer (score 6):

"Im Hinterkopf" would be the most appropriate translation of "in the back of my mind".

The word "[Hintergedanke](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hintergedanke)n" may refer to a concealed intention you have while stating a different. Also it can be related to indirect consequences caused by your actions which you are aware of. Example:

> Mit dem Hintergedanken, dass jemand ausrutschen könnte, legte ich
>   Banenenschalen auf den Gehweg.

However, "*[...] jedoch liebte ich sie so oder so.*" would be more appropriate because "[sowieso](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sowieso)" is mainly used for confirming statements which are already acknowledged as legit or are legit regardless if the discussed subject is.

Answer (score 5):

> In the back of my mind I knew she wasn't right for me, but I loved her anyway.

Das würde ich übersetzen als

> Mein Bauch sagte mir, dass sie nicht die Richtige war, dennoch liebte ich sie.

(*anyway* heißt hier *trotzdem* oder *dennoch*, nicht *sowieso*)

Comment: Wer es nicht soo körperlich mag, kann auch "Ein dumpfes Gefühl sagte mir ..." nehmen.

Comment: @Ingo stimmt. Man könnte das auch weiter umstellen zu *Obwohl ich das dumpfe Gefühl hatte, dass sie nicht die Richtige war, liebte ich sie.*

Comment: Und wer es noch körperlicher mag, kann `Ich hatte es im Urin …` nehmen.